# How to get the post date upon submit?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

How can I automatically push a date as property into Firebase? Here's the function for adding a book with alertcontrol method.

```
addBook() {
console.log("add book button click-ed");

let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Book Title and Author',
  message: 'Book Cover',
  inputs: [
    {
      name: 'title',
      placeholder: 'Book Title'
    },
    {
      name: 'author',
      placeholder: 'Author of the Book'
    },
    {
      name: 'cover',
      placeholder: 'Cover URL'
    },
  ],
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      handler: data => {
        console.log('Cancel click-ed')
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Save Book',
      handler: data => {
        this.books.push({
          title: data.title,
          author: data.author,
          cover: data.cover,
        })
      }
    }
  ]
})
alert.present();
```

}

I've set the prop input for title, author, and covers. It works fine. The `addBook()` function binds to a button that has that method. But how should I go if I want to get the post date and add it to Firebase as props 'date' when user clicked the button?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#server-timestamps